# Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting: How to add a self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to add a SSL certificate (self-signed) to the self-hosting option? If so, how do I accomplish that?

```
"commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls=http://localhost:5000",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For WebListener certificates must be configured prior to launching the server. See these related instructions for HttpListener:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Selfhosting